# Making Family tree and Remembering Parent nodes in tree

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, gridview

I tried my best to be as clear and brief as possible...

I am trying to make a family tree like an animal has father and mother and that father and mother and has father(grand father of that animal) and mother(grand mother of that animal). And I want to store that tree representation in any table like structure.
I might have made a mistake but here is general idea of the input and the output i want

[image]

For this I have developed the following algorithm

```
Table table = new Table();
foreach(row in resultSet)
{
   int i = 1; int r = 1;
   AddAncestersOf(row.Cells[1], resultSet, table.Row[r], i);
   r++;
}
```

Definition of *AddAncestersOf*

```
void AddAncestersOf(String A, ResultSet set, TableRow tableRow, int level)
{
   Select aRow From set Where setCol1 = A;//select row where animalID is A
   if(aRow.Col[2] and aRow.Col[3] are not empty)//if animal has father and mother
   {
      tableRow.Col[(2*i)]=aRow.Col[2];//store father of that animal
      tableRow.Col[(2*i)+1]=aRow.Col[3];//store mother of that animal
      AddAncestersOf(row.Col[2], set, tableRow, level+1);
      AddAncestersOf(row.Col[3], set, tableRow, level+1);
   }
}
```

Firstly if anyone can tell me a better solution please help me...

Second and more major issue is that I want to remember the hierarchy as i go down in the tree with reference to the animal in the root if S for father and D for mother then I want my table column's headings like

A S D SS SD SSS SSD SSSS SSSD SDS SDD SDSS and so on.

As these heading are according to the recursion structure i can do that before these lines in *AddAncestersOf*

```
      //set appropriate heading of tableRow.Col[(2*i)]
      tableRow.Col[(2*i)]=aRow.Col[2];//store father of that animal
      //set appropriate heading of tableRow.Col[(2*i)+1]
      tableRow.Col[(2*i)+1]=aRow.Col[3];//store mother of that animal
```

I am thinking in term of storing the S and D in some structure like stack or queue as i go deep in the tree and setting the Heading by removing all S and D from that structure and appending those to the heading and then append one more S or D in the end accordingly.

Algorithm Closest to implementation would be better.. for implementation i would use C# in ASP.net and for table i need to fill a GridView. Please if someone knows how to do it HELP! and again any better ideas would be great!

Comment: A family tree is, well, structured as a tree. While it is of course possible to store a tree structure in a twodimensional array (looks like you are working in a spreadsheet), using an actual tree structure makes more sense. Could you elaborate a bit on your requirements for tools/language?

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention i need to implement this on a Web App for which i am using ASP.net C# and  to be precise i need to fill a GridView.

Comment: Can you provide a small example of input data and desired output?

Comment: Please review my post i have added some input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you build a binary tree from the ResultRet data using a hash. Hash keys are the A column, hash data are a two-element array with S and D, or a nil-type value to indicate no parent data.

Given your requirements for output, I think your recursive approach is a good choice (I rewrote it slightly, but the logic should be the same as in your algorithm).

The headings are built based on the binary representation of the column indices, noticing the 0s and 1s correspond to S and D, ignoring the most significant digit.

I can unfortunately not give you a c# answer, but I hope this ruby code will serve as good enough pseudo code:

```
# This hash should be created from the ResultRet data.
# One entry for each row.
$h=Hash[
       "A03",["A02","A01"],
       "A02",["A04","A11"],
       "A05",["A02","A01"],
       "A06",nil,
       "A07",["A08","A09"],
       "A08",["A05","A06"],
       "A11",nil,
]

# Make a 2d array:
# (initialized with dashes (to make output more readable))
# Select appropriate dimensions if your grid is not dynamic.
grid=Array.new(8)
(0..8).each{|i| grid[i]=Array.new(20,"-")}

# Fill out one line/row with ancestors of animal given by id.
# The row will stay constant throughout the recursion.
def recurse(row,id,pos)
  # Avoid going too far back:
  return if pos>=2**(4+1)  # max 4 generations back. 
  # store this animal at the given pos:
  row[pos]=id
  # Stop recursing if no parents are defined for this id:
  return unless $h[id]
  # We get parents of id directly by looking up in the hash
  sire,dam = $h[id]
  # Each generation back doubles in size.
  # This calculates the starting column for the parents of id:
  pos*=2
  # continue recursing for the parents
  recurse(row,sire,pos)   
  recurse(row,dam ,pos+1)
end

# Fill inn the result grid, one row at a time:
# This iterates over the keys in the hash.
# (Could also iterate over first columnt in the source data.)
$h.keys.each_with_index{|key,i|
  recurse(grid[i],key,1)
}

# headings:
print "           A"
(2..19).each{|i|
  head=i.to_s(2)[1..-1].gsub("0","S").gsub("1","D")
  print "%6s"%head
}
puts

# print the grid
grid.each{|row|
  row.each{|cell|
    print "%6s"%cell

  }
  puts
}
```

Output:
(extra column due to zero-based index of my grid)

```
       A     S     D    SS    SD    DS    DD   SSS   SSD   SDS   SDD   DSS   DSD   DDS   DDD  SSSS  SSSD  SSDS  SSDD
 -   A03   A02   A01   A04   A11     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -   A02   A04   A11     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -   A05   A02   A01   A04   A11     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -   A06     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -   A07   A08   A09   A05   A06     -     -   A02   A01     -     -     -     -     -     -   A04   A11     -     -
 -   A08   A05   A06   A02   A01     -     -   A04   A11     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -   A11     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
 -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -
```

Comment: Good idea! but please can you describe all this in more general language independent way? Specially how you corrected the recursion sequence to generate the required ordered output?.. I can't fully understand all of that as i don't have a slightest idea of ruby...

Comment: I edited to add more comments. I didn't correct your recursive algorithm, I merely reorganized it a bit. Let me know if there still are any unclear parts.

Comment: No. Thanks a lot. Every thing is making sense now. That was clever specially noticing the binary bit patter for headings... Now I have all the ideas refined thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data environment, I would consider a tree structure with links going both up and down. More than one separate tree would likely be in the data, so it would be good idea to keep a list of the nodes with no descendants, and maybe a list of nodes with no ancestors.